# Is there an API for the blue email address bubbles?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, macos

Is there an API that will let me reproduce the blue round email address bubbles easily?  You see these bubbles in Mail on MacOS and on the iPhone.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the ones in the address fields? The capsules around the names of each recipient?

Comment: Yes, exactly! I think outis has the right answer.  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get a rounded label simply include the QuartzCore-Framework in your project and add this to your .m file:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Then create a regular `UILabel *label`. Set the font, textColor, backgroundColor as you like and then add rounded Corners:

```
label.layer.cornerRadius = label.frame.size.height/2;
```

Comment: You can also add a border by setting the borderWidth and borderColor.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Use the [NSTokenField](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTokenField_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class.

Comment: Don't think this is available on the iPhone.

Comment: You're right, looks like it isn't available for the iPhone.  =(

Comment: see my response on how to do this on the iPhone

Answer (score 4):

Might want to take a look at [Numeric badges on the iPhone](http://scientificninja.com/development/numeric-badges-on-the-iphone).

Another alternative is the [Three20](http://github.com/facebook/three20) project. Its samples shows a method for compositing 'badges.'

Comment: Thanks, those alternatives look nice!